# Why can't I create a table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, database-restore

We previously had a database in MySQL.  In it, we had a table called `trace`.  We've long since dropped the entire database and created another one with the same name.  Now, we try to re-create the table `trace` from a backup script and we get `table already exists`.  Even though there are clearly no tables in the new database.  If I try to create a table that existed before, I get that error.  If I create a random table that never existed then it's fine.

Here is the code I am using to create the table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Trace`;
CREATE TABLE `Trace` (
  `TraceKey` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Trace Key',
  `TableName` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Table Name',
  `RecordKey` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `Action` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ActionTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Time Stamp',
  `UserName` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'UserName',
  PRIMARY KEY (`TraceKey`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6735 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Error:

```
Table 'trace' already exists
```

We did have about 20 tables (trace was one of many) and there were lots of foreign keys if that helps.  But we clearly dropped the DB and recreated it.

**UPDATE**

For testing, I tried this and it WORKS

```
CREATE TABLE trace (id INT,data VARCHAR(100));
```

However, after dropping that table and trying it again like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Trace (id INT,data VARCHAR(100));
```

It doesn't work and I get the `trace already exists` error.

The difference is upper vs lowercase??

**UPDATE 2**

It is definitely an uppercase vs lowercase issue.  Changing the table name from `Trace` to `trace` works even using the old script.

Any ideas on why this is so?

Comment: What does `SHOW TABLES` show? Is table `trace` present in its output?

Comment: `SHOW TABLES` comes up blank.

Comment: This is not really related to programming i.e. your sql is correct and is not the problem, I would suggest that this question be asked at server fault or database administrators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have wrong `lower_case_table_names` setting set on your MySQL Server. Correct values can be found [In MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html). It states:

> If you are using MySQL on only one platform, you do not normally have to change the lower_case_table_names variable from its default
>   value. However, you may encounter difficulties if you want to transfer
>   tables between platforms that differ in file system case sensitivity.
>   For example, on Unix, you can have two different tables named my_table
>   and MY_TABLE, but on Windows these two names are considered identical.
>   To avoid data transfer problems arising from lettercase of database or
>   table names, you have two options:
>
> 1. Use lower_case_table_names=1 on all systems. The main disadvantage with this is that when you use SHOW TABLES or SHOW
>      DATABASES, you do not see the names in their original lettercase.
> 2. Use lower_case_table_names=0 on Unix and lower_case_table_names=2 on Windows. This preserves the lettercase of
>      database and table names. The disadvantage of this is that you must
>      ensure that your statements always refer to your database and table
>      names with the correct lettercase on Windows. If you transfer your
>      statements to Unix, where lettercase is significant, they do not work
>      if the lettercase is incorrect.
>
>    Exception: If you are using InnoDB tables and you are trying to avoid these data transfer problems, you should set
>      lower_case_table_names to 1 on all platforms to force names to be
>      converted to lowercase.

If you're using MySQL on Windows and have `lower_case_table_names=0` then you might get this error because table `Trace` (case-sensitive) does not exist in MySQL but file `Trace.frm` already exists on file system.

Comment: I believe this helped me the most.  I manually changed our script to use lowercase table names and it all worked.  I will look into setting the correct config as mentioned above.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you restart your database server. I got similar problem before.